# Calling /ardrone/togglecam from python code rather than from terminal

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have difficulty that I am able to use ($rosservice call /ardrone/togglecam) command from terminal to toggle between front and bottom camera of AR Drone but same I am not able to do from my python code.

I am using:

## to generate publishing command

Self.Pubtogglec = rospy.Publisher(‘/ardrone/togglecam’, Empty)

#Then I have defined a function to finally publish this command to ardrone
Def ToggleBCam(self)
Self.Pubtgglec.publish(Empty())

My code is reaching to this ToggleBCam method (as I am printing some massage there to see if it reaches to this publish line or not) but this is not changing video feed. I am not sure what exactly wrong I am doing. I have search extensively but I have not found any help either. Can you please help me, how I can toggle camera from my python code? I habve seen some of the old tutorial methods have used above mentioned method for toggling cam but why I am not able to do that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215536/calling-/ardrone/togglecam-from-python-code-rather-than-from-terminal/) by [AmitShukla_IITK](https://answers.ros.org/users/23524/amitshukla_iitk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot call a service using a publisher.
This is simply the wrong way to do this.

You need to use a ServiceClient. Have a look at the [python tutorial on creating a ServiceClient (or ServiceProxy)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node) for how to do this.
Then, use the respective service type in your script.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2